# How to restart video track after stopping it in twilio?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twilio, webrtc, twilio-video

I am using twilio-video v2.7.

**Objective:**

Restart the video track after stopping it.

**Use case:**

Turn off the camera led indicator when video is off and vice-versa just like google meet.

```
const toggleVideo = () => {
    const isOff = !isVideoOn;
    room.localParticipant.videoTracks.forEach((t) => {
      if (isOff) {
        t.track.enable();
        t.track.attach(screenRef.current)
      } else {
        t.track.disable();
        t.track.stop()
        t.unpublish()
        t.track.detach()
      }
    });
    setVideoToggle(isOff);
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

A while ago I used this code to mute/unmute media. You can change it as you like. If there is anything not clear let me now in the comments.

```js
/**
 * Mute/unmute your media in a Room.
 * @param {Room} room - The Room you have joined
 * @param {'audio'|'video'} kind - The type of media you want to mute/unmute
 * @param {'mute'|'unmute'} action - Whether you want to mute/unmute
 */
function muteOrUnmuteYourMedia(room, kind, action) {
  const publications = kind === 'audio'
    ? room.localParticipant.audioTracks
    : room.localParticipant.videoTracks;

  publications.forEach(function(publication) {
    if (action === 'mute') {
      publication.track.disable();
    } else {
      publication.track.enable();
    }
  });
}
/**
 * Mute your video in a Room.
 * @param {Room} room - The Room you have joined
 * @returns {void}
 */
function muteYourVideo(room) {
  muteOrUnmuteYourMedia(room, 'video', 'mute');
}
/**
 * UnMute your video in a Room.
 * @param {Room} room - The Room you have joined
 * @returns {void}
 */
function muteYourVideo(room) {
  muteOrUnmuteYourMedia(room, 'video', 'unmute');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to re-publish the video track. As long as you are handling the event for on track published, this should suffice.

t.track.publish()